# Question regarding differences in calculating T statistics in Python for the difference in means

Tags: python, statistics

I am re-learning introductory statistics and wanted to try implementing my own versions of the general and unpooled formulas that find the T Value. I implemented it in 2 ways, one by just replicating the formulas as is as Python Functions. The other was to use Python's ability to generate a normal distribution and use that to find the difference in means. But I noticed my values were pretty different in both versions. So my question is why is there a difference? Is it with how the function works itself?

Here's the "generate a distribution itself" method:

```
from numpy.random import seed
from numpy.random import normal
from scipy import stats
from datetime import datetime
import math

#Plan: Generate 2 random normal distributions of the desired critiera. And T Test them
data1 = normal(loc=65.2, scale=7.8, size=30)
data2 = normal(loc=70.3, scale=8.4, size=30)

stats.ttest_ind(a=data1, b=data2)

Ttest_indResult(statistic=-2.029830829733737, pvalue=0.04696953433513939)
```

As you can see, it gives a T statistic of ~-2.0298 and a p value of ~ 0.0470.

Here's my "manual version":

```
def pop_2_mean_pooled_t(mean1, mean2, s1, s2, n1, n2):
    dof = (n1+n2)-2
    mean_diff = mean1 - mean2
    #The N part on the right
    right_n = math.sqrt((1/n1) + (1/n2))
    #The Sp part
    sp_numereator_left = ((n1-1)*(s1**2))
    sp_numberator_right = ((n2-1)*(s2**2))
    sp = math.sqrt((sp_numereator_left + sp_numberator_right)/(dof))
    pooled_sp = sp*right_n
    t = mean_diff/pooled_sp
    p = stats.t.cdf(t, dof)
    print("T is " +str(t))
    print("p is " +str(p))
    return t, p


pop_2_mean_pooled_t(65.2, 70.3, 7.8, 8.4, 30, 30)

T is -2.4368742610942298
p is 0.00895208222413155

(-2.4368742610942298, 0.00895208222413155)
```

As you can see, it gives a T statistic of ~-2.439 and a p value of ~ 0.009.

My question is why is there a discrepancy here? My "manual version" is closer to the example I was referencing. But surely the generator one should also be?

My understanding is that if a sample is significantly large enough, it would resemble a normal distribution. Therefore, one could generate a normal distribution using code and use that to approximate the corresponding T Values. For some reason, that differed quite a bit from my "manual" version

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is basically correct (I did not check your formulae though). What your encountering is in the nature of the problem: the two random samples you're drawing are, well, *random* and they differ in subsequent runs, so you will always get a different p-value ant the t-statistics.

Two suggestions from me:

1. increase the sample size in the first snippet to hundreds (not 30): you should get much closer to the stats from the second snippet.
2. keep  30 samples in the first snippet but run the simulation several times; you will learn the distributions of p-values and t-statistics and, again, you can check the values from your second snippet against the simulated distributions.

(Some conceptual flaws occur in this approach, e.g. repeated testing affects the p-value, but let us put them aside for now; the goal is to see your two sets of values converge.)